# Resize to add values from one range to another

Tags: excel, vba, sum, resize

The following VBA code runs smoothly to sum up two ranges' value together:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 3 To 5
        Cells(i, 9).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value + Cells(i, 7).Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I tried to use resize method as another options and rewrite it as below but encountered a type unmatched error:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim range2 As Range
    Dim result As Range

    Set range1 = Range("I3:I5")
    Set range2 = Range("G3:G5")

    Set result = range1.Resize(range2.Rows.Count, range2.Columns.Count)
    ' Option 1
    result.Value = range1.Value + range2.Value
    ' Option 2
    result.Value = CInt(range1.Value) + CInt(range2.Value)
    
End Sub
```

Please help me dig out what's the problems and fix it. Thanks advance.

I need a solution to fix it.

Comment: it would be best if you could post a pic of your sample data and desired result

Comment: `range1.value` (for example) is a 2D array of values: you can't add arrays like that or pass them to `CInt()`

Comment: With a recorded macro as shown below, It's easily to get what I wanted. 

    Range("G3:G5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("I3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlAdd, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
 
What confused me is that If just skipped the portion to be added up onto the target range, it's workable as compared  as follows:

Range("K3:K5").Value = Range("G3:G5").Value + Range("K3:K5").Value -> type mismatch
Range("K3:K5").Value = Range("G3:G5").Value -> Accepted 
Please give me more explanation. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

### Accumulate Column

**Efficient**

- In general, to be efficient, you would want to avoid any kind of loop, if possible.
- On the other hand, looping over the elements of an array, instead of over cells of a range, is much more efficient.

```vb
Sub AccumulateColumnEfficient()
    
    Const ACC_ADDRESS As String = "I3:I5"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As String = "G"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim arg As Range: Set arg = ws.Range(ACC_ADDRESS)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = arg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COLUMN)
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = arg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim aData(), sData()
    
    If rCount = 1 Then ' single cell
        ReDim aData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): aData(1, 1) = arg.Value
        ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = srg.Value
    Else ' multiple cells
        aData = arg.Value
        sData = srg.Value
    End If
    
    Dim sValue, aValue, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sValue = sData(r, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then
            aValue = aData(r, 1)
            If IsNumeric(aValue) Then
                aData(r, 1) = aValue + sValue
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    arg.Value = aData
    
End Sub
```

- Note that if you are sure there are only numbers you could simplify the loop (no *If* statements, no `sValue` and `aValue`) with

  ```
  aData(r, 1) = aData(r, 1) + sData(r, 1)
  ```

  (not recommended)

**Worksheet.Evaluate**

- In this case, you could avoid a loop but it is questionable (benchmark it (measure the time) and let us know) if it would be more efficient, especially with tens of thousands of rows. At least you'll have fewer lines of code (should never be the main reason for choosing a code).

```vb
Sub AccumulateColumnEvaluate()
    
    Const ACC_ADDRESS As String = "I3:I5"
    Const SRC_COLUMN As String = "G"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    With ws.Range(ACC_ADDRESS)
        Dim sAddress As String:
        sAddress = .EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COLUMN).Address(0, 0)
        Dim EvalString As String:
        EvalString = "IF(ISNUMBER(" & sAddress & "),IF(ISNUMBER(" _
            & ACC_ADDRESS & ")," & ACC_ADDRESS & "+" & sAddress _
            & "," & ACC_ADDRESS & ")," & ACC_ADDRESS & ")"
        'Debug.Print EvalString
        ' Debug.Print Result:
        ' IF(ISNUMBER(G3:G5),IF(ISNUMBER(I3:I5),I3:I5+G3:G5,I3:I5),I3:I5)
        .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate(EvalString)
    End With
    
End Sub
```

- Note that if you are sure there are only numbers you can simplify (no *IF* statements) with

  ```
  EvalString = ACC_ADDRESS & "+" & sAddress
  ```

  (not recommended)

Comment: What if the source range and target range are in two separated tables the method is the same as the range in a worksheet without table? I was told that Application.CutCopyMode does not clear the clipboard, That's why I gave up the easy way by recording a macro and tried to find a resize method in a table. In view of your code it seems workable whether the data exist in tables or not.

Comment: With 657,920 rows running 5 times the sub routine AccumulateColumnEfficient() takes up to 00:05.08 while AccumulateColumnEvaluate() takes 00:06.45. The latter returns zero for each cell in I column in the first run.